# Big O for factorials

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, factorial

Hello I have trouble proving:$$(n+1)!\notin O(n!)$$ My first step is the following: $$(n+1)!-cn!\le0$$ Can you please help me with the next step?

Comment: well I get that but I need to prove it.

Comment: In that case, you should probably rephrase your question to "proving that this is false," to make it clear that you know which result to aim for. Simplify the expression and get $n + 1 - c \le 0$, which can't hold for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)!}{n!}=\lim_{n\to \infty} (n+1) = +\infty$$

which implies $(n+1)!$ is not $O(n!)$.